# get next top left position of HTMLElement before rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, getboundingclientrect

Is there a way to figure out where the next HTML Element would land before rendering it (Top Left position)?

PS 
I found this question:
[JavaScript: Check width of a <div> object before placing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744657/javascript-check-width-of-a-div-object-before-placing-it)

But because the guy needs the width, he has less options.
They actually also suggest placing a hidden element.

I am not using JQuery, just plain Javascript.

Comment: you can only check the position of element once its loaded... unless all elements have fixed width and height.. you can calculate everything down to padding, margins, font-size and line height.. there no simpler way to achieve that...

Comment: You could always insert it and just have it hidden until you need it

Comment: ok thanks... now i still need to figure out how exactly I get to the topleft of this component.. any suggestions? it is an absolute placed object 'inside' a relative component.

Comment: ok i got it - the rectangle option on temp object works fine. Thanks for confirming.